# Does console log increase memory on nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, v8

I have some important **console** logs for some strings and objects on a **NodeJs** server for each API request.

Already we move a copy of these logs to log files.

Does the **console** log for these objects will increase the memory usage for each request as they kept in the **console** , for example if we have 1 million request.

For example

```
console.log('some data here', new Date())
```

Comment: It depends, personally I don't believe that `console.log` itself will ever impact your application's performance and increase your application's memory usage

Comment: Thank you Felix,  but kindly i need a technical answer not feeling

Comment: How exactly are you structure your `console.log`, can you give us a hint so we can further discuss?

Comment: simple `console.log('some data here')`

Comment: Have you ran into a problem with console.log consuming memory? or is this just a feeling.

Comment: I have increment memory after each request, it never go down. i didn't store any thing. just doing some logs

Comment: Have you removed the console.log, to prove that the console.log is the cause? Can you share these results with the class?

Comment: they are many logs, but you are right i will ask for check this point. i was asking if there some one who faced same issue

Comment: thanks @KevinB for idea

Comment: Sorry for giving my falsely "conclusion" so early, and the answer will simply be "Yes" you will run into problem by overloading your system

Comment: can you make it as an answer @FelixFong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes

[`console.log`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L283) invokes [`util.formatWithOptions`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L75) internally. The formatted string goes to [the output stream](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L213) (stdout, stderr for example).
During the formatting, some variables are created.

The formatted string is a new variable that is referenced until the process write it to the file descriptor.

So, yes for every `console.log` call, some variables are created. The memory increase depends what and how many times your code logs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - due to the facts that by nature in Linux, `console.log` itself is synchronous.

So by giving it a large chunk of data to log inside the standard output while being very spammy will actually cost some performance issues

[Edit]

This might help solve the issue where production application needs to log a large amount of data while being very performance

https://surfingthe.cloud/dont-fear-node-js-console-log